# How to evaluate the value in a svelte store string

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I'm trying to evaluate whether or not a user is logged in, in order to show some other information. So far, I've been trying to do this using svelte stores.

## userContext.js:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const loginStatus = writable('log in');
```

## App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { loginStatus } from './userContext.js';
</script>

{#if {$loginStatus} === "log in"}
        <p>Please log in</p>
{/if}
```

This doesn't work because I can't seem to evaluate strings that are stores inside the svelte stores. How can I make that work? And if that's not possible, how can I do this simple logged in user flow with svelte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not surround `$loginStatus` with `{}`. `$loginStatus` is enough to dereference the store value.

**[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0744cd7c80274dbe80c72ddf18b6fa08?version=3.20.1)**

```html
{#if $loginStatus === "log in"}
  <p>Please log in</p>
{/if}
```